# C read formatted line with spaces from FILE*

Tags: c, xml, date

Suppose we have stream as a FILE* type and it contains some xml data. What I need is parse a tag value, but the problem is there are values that contain spaces, such as date. So, xml date value is represented like '<Date>value</Date>' and I need to extract the value in a single string or 2 separate - doesn't really matter.

```
FILE* stream = readXML();//some generic method that returns FILE*
if(stream!=NULL){
     char line[64];
     while((fgets(line, sizeof(line), stream))!=NULL){
          char date[22];
          if(sscanf(line,"<Date>%[^\n]</Date>", date)){
               // perform some actions
          }else{
               printf("Parse failed");
          }
     }
}
```

The problem with the code above is that I get the value in the following form:
2015-05-10 19:20:21.0</Date>
 supposing that the xml line looks like: <Date>2015-05-10 19:20:21.0</Date>
What is wrong with the sscanf method format?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first character that you don't want is the left angle bracket, so make that part of your exclusion list `[^...]`:

```
if (sscanf(line, "<Date>%[^<]</Date>", date) == 1) ...
```

It is a good idea to allow only dates that will fit in your char buffer `date` by specifying a maximum width in the `%` format specifier:

```
if (sscanf(line, "<Date>%21[^<]</Date>", date) == 1) ...
```

Comment: Cool! It worked! Please correct me if I am wrong, as I understood, what this format does is select any character after <Date> until the first occurrence of left angle bracket. Is it so?

Comment: Yes. The notation `%[...]` selects a stretch of the characters that are given between the brackets. The caret reverses that: `%[^...]` selects a stretch of characters that are not in the given set. In your case, scanning stops either at the first left angle bracket or at the end of the string if there are no left angle brackets in the string.